# Calculate length of 2,000 paths - lines in Google Earth?

Tags: shapefile, google-maps, cartography, google-earth

I have ~2,000 paths/lines drawn in Google Earth and I would like to know their cumulative length. How can I do this easily?

I have been able to convert into excel the Lat & Long of each point in the string, but some are too long for Excel to accept.
Dylan

Answer (score 1):

in excel, you can use following formule (from [Excel formula to calculate distance between 2 latitude, longitude (lat/lon) points (GPS positions)](http://bluemm.blogspot.com/2007/01/excel-formula-to-calculate-distance.html)):

```
=ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-A2)) *COS(RADIANS(90-A3)) +SIN(RADIANS(90-A2)) *SIN(RADIANS(90-A3)) 
*COS(RADIANS(B2-B3))) *6371
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: I guess that's not very accurate...